# could not access file "$libdir/plpgsql" while creating template_postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have installed PostgreSQL and Postgis on my Mac before when it's 9.3 and 2.1 but never used.
After upgrading pg to 4.5_2 and postgis to 2.2 (the latest now), I try to build my first postgis based app and creating template_postgis like this:

```
createdb template_postgis
psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/local/share/postgis/postgis.sql
```

And got this error:

```
SET
BEGIN
psql:/usr/local/share/postgis/postgis.sql:77: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpgsql": No such file or directory
...
```

So I run `pg_config --libdir` it says `/usr/local/lib`, and `pg_config --pkglibdir` returns `/usr/local/lib/postgresql`.
And I found `plpgsql.so` under pkglibdir not libdir,
so I create a symbol link named plpgsql.so and another plpgsql under libdir, but it still not works.

What really is the problem there? How can I fix this?

My Mac is running the newest OS X 10.11 and both of them are installed and upgraded by homebrew.

Update:
Inspired by @Stefan D. , I run `psql -c "\dx"` to list all the installed extensions which results:

```
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                             Description
---------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis | 2.1.7   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
```

So I run `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.2.0";` to manually update the version of postgis, but got another error: `could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`.

This is wired as my PostgreSQL is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/`. And `postgis.control` is not listed in `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/share/postgresql/extension/`  either.

After locating, I find all the `.control` files have an symbol link in `/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I got out what caused this issue: Although there's only one postgres installed on my Mac, but there are **TWO** postgres exits!

What really happened is I have upgraded postgres program without shutting down, neither brew did, so I have a postgres 9.4.5_2 installed locally, and an old one in the memory!

So the solutions is really simple: Shutting down the old one and start the new installed postgres!

Anyway, thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 6):

What a coinincidence: I just had a similar problem and were searching for a solution when I found your question.

I also updated my postgresql/postgis installation a couple of days ago, and when I wanted to use my database (which I created with before the update) it today I got an error similiar to yours (for me it was that the postgis 2.1 library could not be found)

Meanwhile I could fix it. Here is how I did it:

My problem was: The database was set up with the old Postgresql/postgis version. And it still looks for the old libraries. You can check this by listing all your extensions with the following command:

```
psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "\dx"
```

For me this gave me this output:

```
                                         List of installed extensions
       Name       | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis          | 2.1.7   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology | 2.1.7   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(3 rows)
```

As you can see the `postgis` and `postgis_topology` extension versions (`2.1.7`) do not fit my installed versions (`2.2.0`)
To fix that I executed the following commands to update the extension versions:

```
psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;"
psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE;"
```

You will probably have to alter the command a bit (username, database, and the extension you want to update)

Check whether it worked again with:
    psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "\dx"

Now the output is:

```
                                         List of installed extensions
       Name       | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis          | 2.2.0   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology | 2.2.0   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(3 rows)
```

(Note the changed version number for `postgis` and `postgis_topology`)

Comment: My state is that only plpgsql 1.0 is installed in the ``template_postgis`` database. How could I install the postgis plugin for this template database?

Comment: I installed the PostGIS extension like that:

    `psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"  `   


    `psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"`

Here is what I did from installing Postgresql /postgis to importing OSM map data: https://cervisial.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/setting-up-postgresql-postgis/

Comment: I could not add a linebreak between the commands. Its two commands: First: `psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"`
And second: `psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"`

Comment: Same error as I mentioned: ``ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory``. I think the key point may be why isn't postgis.control installed correctlly?

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me in the right direction for figuring out a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably You have installed **multipe instances** of Postgres on Your Mac.

When you execute `pg_config  --pkglibdir`, make sure it's the one associated with your installation. Run:

```
which pg_config
```

Comment: I'm sure that I have only one installed in ``/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/``.